# Count Checkboxes using JQuery. Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, checkbox

I have a table with some checkboxes and I need to make a count every time 1 is selected. I have 2 lines and I have to count each line separately.

Here are the checkboxes:

```
{!! Form::checkbox('dente[]', $dente->id, null, ['class'=>'denteCheck-up'] ) !!}

{!! Form::checkbox('dente[]', $dente->id, null, ['class'=>'denteCheck-down'] ) !!}
```

The goal is always that 1 is selected it counts in real time and puts the result here:

```
<td id="count_dentes_up"></td>

<td id="count_dentes_down"></td>
```

For this and thanks to the help of a user of this community, I am using the following jquery code:

```
$('.denteCheck-up').change(function() {
  $('#count_dentes_up').text($('.denteCheck-up:checked').length);
});

$('.denteCheck-down').change(function() {
  $('#count_dentes_down').text($('.denteCheck-down:checked').length);
});
```

The problem is that in code snippets it works wonderfully but I can not get it to work at all. To help I'm using Laravel 5.4 and I'm incorporating the following scripts:

```
    {{-- Scripts --}}

    {{-- Bootstrap JS Library File--}}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    {{-- jQuery Charts --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

    {{-- Js Project file --}}
    <script src="{{asset('js/script.js')}}"></script>

    {{-- Datepiker --}}
    <script src="{{asset('js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js')}}"></script>

    {{-- jQuery-ui Library File --}}
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You might try to reorder libraries and put jquery.ui after jquery.slim

Comment: In my understanding you are loading dynamic html in some way. So are you attaching the events at `document.onload`? Please put the html page here.

Comment: Please show relevant html...not server side template code